# slideDown jumps in Jquery within a bootstrap row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slidedown

I'm trying to use slideDown in conjunction with a few divs that I dynamically load on my page.
Problem is that the slide down slides only until the last element of the div, but no further than that.

It means that it "misses" the last row of the div and doesn't slide smoothly, it just jumps until the end of the div.

[image: Slidedown jumping]

```
<div id="toslide">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- printer.materials == ['PLA': [[blue, 22, 2(material id)], [red, 23, 3]], 'ABS': [[yellow, 22, 6], ...]]-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class='select select-primary select-block mbl'
                    name="material">
                    <option value="value">value</option>
            </select>

            <select class='select' 
                    name="color" onchange="update_breakdown(this.id)">

                    <option value="value">12(USD)</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
     $("#toSlide").hide().html(data);
     $("#toSlide").slideDown("slow");
</script>
```

For simplicity I removed some Ajax code, but I think you can get the idea.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your `#toSlide` div inside any other div?

Comment: Yes it is inside another div like this:
    <div class="panel-body">
         <div id="toslide1">  ........

         </div>          
    </div>

Comment: Does the parent div has positioning set? Note that bootstrap sets relative position to all `col-lg-, col-md-, col-sm-,col-xs-` classes

Comment: The only other parent is a container div.

Comment: What about `body` and `html`?

Comment: I meant other div..
You're right those are other parents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67647/discussion-between-cyberjoac-and-morpheus).

Comment: I have the same problem using BS3. The obvious solution is to use the "collapse()" function of BS3. Unfortunately I can't load BS js on my site, so I have to do it "by hand" with jquery. It should not be a problem, but there seems to be a bug with BS3 grid and slideDown(). JQuery must calculate the width of the animated element and I thinks the element height is 0px when inside a row... Did you find a solution?